# OpenCV GrabCut Mask

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have utilised the OpenCV GrabCut functionality to perform an image segmentation. When viewing the segmented image as per the code below, the segmentation is reasonable/correct. However, when looking at(at attempting to use) the segmrntation mask values, I am getting some very large numbers, and not the enumerated values one would expect from the `cv::GrabCutClasses` enum.

```
void doGrabCut(){
        Vector2i imgDims = getImageDims();

        //Wite image to OpenCV Mat.
        const Vector4u *rgb = getRGB();
        cv::Mat rgbMat(imgDims.height, imgDims.width, CV_8UC3);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgDims.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgDims.width; j++) {
                int idx = i * imgDims.width + j;
                rgbMat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i)[j][2] = rgb[idx].x;
                rgbMat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i)[j][1] = rgb[idx].y;
                rgbMat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i)[j][0] = rgb[idx].z;
            }
        }

        //Do graph cut.
        cv::Mat res, fgModel, bgModel;
        cv::Rect bb(bb_begin.x, bb_begin.y, bb_end.x - bb_begin.x, bb_end.y - bb_begin.y);
        cv::grabCut(rgbMat, res, bb, bgModel, fgModel, 10, cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
        cv::compare(res, cv::GC_PR_FGD, res, cv::CMP_EQ);

        //Write mask.
        Vector4u *maskPtr = getMask();//uchar
        for (int i = 0; i < imgDims.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgDims.width; j++) {
                cv::GrabCutClasses classification = res.at<cv::GrabCutClasses>(i, j);
                int idx = i * imgDims.width + j;
                std::cout << classification << std::endl;//Strange numbers here.
                maskPtr[idx].x = (classification == cv::GC_PR_FGD) ? 255 : 0;//This always evaluates to 0.
            }
        }

        cv::Mat foreground(rgbMat.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        rgbMat.copyTo(foreground, res);
        cv::imshow("GC Output", foreground);
}
```

Why would one get numbers outside the enumeration when the segmentation is qualitatively correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt on your `//Write mask.` step, why do you re-iterate the `res` and modify `maskPtr` as `maskPtr[idx].x = (classification == cv::GC_PR_FGD) ? 255 : 0;`, Basically you already have a single channel Binary image stored in the `res` variable, the `cv::compare()` returns a binary image

However if you still want to debug the values by iteration then you should use the standard technique for iterating a single channel image as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
        uchar classification = res.at<uchar>(i, j);
        std::cout << int(classification) << ", ";
    }
}
```

As you are iterating a single channel mat you must use `res.at<uchar>(i, j)` and not `res.at<cv::GrabCutClasses>`.